# JSF page lost style after partial update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have some troubles with partial update of jsf 2.0 page.
I have dropdown menu with few choices. Depending on choice I show different page. When I load page first time it shows css and javascript works fine. When I change another option in dropdown menu this part of page which has been re rendered appearing without css and javascript on it doesn't work.

This is example of page itself which I using, template.xhtm and bean are pretty generic therefor I didn't include it.

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<ui:define name="body">

<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.answer}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.answers}" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="includeContainer @All" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>



<h:panelGroup id="includeContainer">
    <h:panelGroup library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"
        rendered="#{bean.answer == 'yes'}">
        <ui:include src="answer_yes.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.asnwer == 'no'}">
        <ui:include src="answer_no.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>


</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

One important remark regarding template that I use this statement to include css, it's located on remote server and I can't download and place it locally, it's company's policy.

```
<link href="http://server.com/resources/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" title="w3" type="text/css" />
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried putting that link inside the rendered panelGroup? - Also, you're rendering includeContainer and @All? thus the first render of includeContainer is kind of redundant. Ahm you have your primefaces jquery on your first panelgroup not your second - add it to both, or put it on the top container.

Comment: `<h:panelGroup library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"` ???

Answer (score 0):

You can put rendered panel group inside an `<h:form id="toberendred">` and re-render this form instead of `h:panelGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

For proper (JSF way) loading your css file from remote server you can use [Omnifaces CDNResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler)

---

In addition you got some serious issues in your code:

Why use `@all` (fix to lowercase) with additional (`includeContainer`) selector? , do view source and see that you can't render `<ui:include` in view source you will see content of both yes and no xhtmls + `<h:panelGroup` got no attributes `library` and `name`...